# How do I get PHP to loop through 2 sets of opening times but skip the closed times in between?

Tags: php

Let me try and explain this as easy as possible.

I have 2 sets of opening times - AM and PM. I want to display dropdown values for every 15 minutes EXCEPT for the times that are closed in between.

I've been at this for like 6 hours and can't get it to work. It must be really simple but I just can't see it. Here's what I have:

```
// Fake the time to 11:31
$timenow = strtotime('11:31');

echo '<select name="delivery_time">';

// Start with 1 hour after current time.
$deliverytime = strtotime('+1 hour', $timenow);

// Round to next 15 minutes
$deliverytime = ceil($deliverytime / (15*60)) * (15*60);

$open_am = strtotime('07:00');
$close_am = strtotime('11:00');
$open_pm = strtotime('13:00');
$close_pm = strtotime('20:00');

while($deliverytime <= $close_am && $deliverytime >= $open_am) {
 echo '<option value="'. date('H:i', $deliverytime) .'">' . date('H:i', $deliverytime) . '</option>'."\n";
 $deliverytime = strtotime('+15 minutes', $deliverytime);
}

echo "</select>";
```

That's where it gets tricky. In order to skip the times in between that are closed (between 11:00 and 13:00) I tried changing it to:

```
while($deliverytime <= $close_am && $deliverytime >= $open_am && (
$deliverytime <= $close_pm && $deliverytime >= $open_pm
)) {
```

But that didn't work. What am I doing wrong? I just can't see it :(

Comment: First I wanna say line 7 has an undeclared variable: $timenow instead of $time_now. Have you tried a for loop instead? For($I=0;$I<=$close_am;$i++){if ($deliverytime >= $open_am){//docode}}?

Comment: @Juan sorry that was a typo when I copied over the code. Will try the loop now..

Comment: You're fine try the for loop and include an if statement that may work better. Can you tell me your output??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright after looking at your question in more in depth, this is what I think you're trying to do:

```
// Started at 0 'cause I felt it more logical (i.e. I'm just lazy)
$time_now = strtotime('00:00'); 

// Consolidated because I hate seeing the same $variable twice, sorry
$deliverytime = ceil( strtotime('+1 hour', $time_now) / (15*60)) * (15*60);

$open_am = strtotime('07:00');
$close_am = strtotime('11:00');
$open_pm = strtotime('13:00');
$close_pm = strtotime('20:00');

echo '<select name="delivery_time">';

// Started with a general comparison so the loop knows its range of loop
while ( $deliverytime <= $close_pm ) { 

    if ( $deliverytime < $open_am ) {
        echo '';
    }
    else if ( $deliverytime >= $close_am && $deliverytime <= $open_pm ) {
        echo '';
    } else {
    echo '<option value="'. date('H:i', $deliverytime) .'">' . date('H:i',        $deliverytime) . '</option>'."\n";

    }
        $deliverytime = strtotime('+15 minutes', $deliverytime);
}

echo "</select>";
```

If I understood you correctly I think this is seems to work. Clarify anything I got wrong and I will modify as necessary (I tried to use a for loop but it got weird)

Comment: That worked perfectly and makes sense. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score -1):

Why not just have two loops?

```
while(... open AM stuff ...) { ... }
while(... open PM stuff ...) { ... }
```

Alternatively, just one loop, using loop control to skip over the lunchbreak:

```
while($open_am -> $closed_pm) {
   if (lunchtime) {
       continue;
   }
   ... output
}
```